# Pagination is not working using WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, theme-development, pagination

I have coded for custom post type pagination but it doesn't work.
Here is some code for it.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$userid = get_current_user_id();
$userData = get_user_meta($userid , 'referat', true);

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'zt_lawyersportal',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'orderby'     => 'modified',
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'referat',
            'value' => $userData,
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
);
$resData = new WP_Query($args); ?>
<div class="post">
    <h2>Posteingang</h2>
    <div class="table-responsive">  
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>                                    
                    <th>postname</th>
                    <th>Aktionen</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="dahboard-tbody">
                <?php
                if ($resData->have_posts()) :
                    while ($resData->have_posts()) :
                        $resData->the_post();
                        ?>
                        <tr onclick="location.href = '<?= get_permalink(); ?>';"  data-rowid="<?= $post->ID; ?>">                                           
                            <td><?= get_the_title(); ?></td>
                            <td class="last">
                                <a class="green" href="<?= get_permalink($post->ID) ?>">Fall anzeigen</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    endwhile;
                else:
                    echo '<tr><td><h2>Keine Fälle gefunden<h2></td></tr>';
                endif;
                wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <?php
            $total_pages = $resData->max_num_pages;
            if ($total_pages > 1) {
                $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
                $page =  paginate_links(array(
                    'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
                    'format' => '/page/%#%',
                    'current' => $current_page,
                    'total' => $total_pages,
                    'prev_text' => __('Prev'),
                    'next_text' => __('Next'),
                    'type' => 'array'
                ));
                echo '<nav aria-label="Page navigation example"><ul class="pagination">';
                foreach ($page as $key => $value) {
                    echo '<li class="page-item">' . $value . '</li>';
                }   
                echo '</ul></nav>';
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way to have page nav for the custom post is to use [WP PageNavi](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/). After activating this plugin you need to add the following code in your custom post template.

```
<?php
    if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) {
        wp_pagenavi( array(
            'query' =>$loop
        ));
    }
```

Comment: No, I don't want to go with a plugin, I believe in custom code here